# Delete lines in files A and B that exist in file A

Tags: python

i am having a problem. I have a blacklist.txt file that contains 5 links

```
Link1.com
Link2.com
Link3.com
Weirdlink4.com
Fivelink5.com
```

I also have a Links.txt which contains all these 5 links and 40 more.
I am trying to make a script that can read what blacklist.txt contains and remove those links from Links.txt and removing the links aswell in blacklist.txt.

```
with open("Blacklist.txt", "w+") as blacklist:
    with open("Links.txt", "w+") as links:
        blackinfo = blacklist.read()
        linksinfo = links.read()
        for i in blackinfo:
            if i in linksinfo:
```

At this point i am completely confused as to how i am going to delete the link from both files because i is holding the value. Thanks in advance

Comment: create a new file instead of deleting from existing ones.

Comment: Won't the whole `blacklist.txt` disappear when you are done?

Comment: `i` will be a single character. You probably want `for line in blacklist:`

Comment: Simple clarification. Should the links in blacklist.txt but not in Links.txt also be removed from blacklist.txt?

Comment: umm that is not neccesarily danny. Every link in blacklist.txt is guaranteed to be in Links.txt I also want blacklist.txt to still exist after the links contained in it have been removed from Links.txt. I can empty blacklist.txt with

  `with open("Blacklist.txt", "w") as blacklist:`
        `Pass`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using list comprehensions you can create a new list of links that you override your link files with:

```
with open("Blacklist.txt", "r+") as blacklist_file :
    with open("Links.txt", "r+") as links_file :

        bl_links = blacklist_file.read().splitlines()
        blacklist_file.seek(0) #reset file handle's position to start of file for writing

        links = links_file.read().splitlines()
        links_file.seek(0)

        # Only keep blacklist links that did not exist in links
        new_blacklist_links = [link for link in bl_links if link not in links]

        # Only keep links that did not exist in the blacklist
        new_links = [link for link in links if link not in bl_links]

        blacklist_file.write('\n'.join(new_blacklist_links))
        blacklist_file.truncate() #truncate the file to what we have just written

        links_file.write('\n'.join(new_links))
        links_file.truncate()
```